# Toggle Contact Form fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I want to toggle some fields depending on what the visitor chooses at this page http://draidel.com.ar/trabaja-con-nosotros/ so I created a dropdown menu with the id **puesto** and the fields to toggle with the class **condicional** then I added this script

```
document.getElementById("puesto").onchange = CamposOcultos(document.getElementById("puesto").value);

function CamposOcultos(valor){
if (valor == "Modelo" or valor == "Promotor/a"){
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('condicional').length;i+=1){
  document.getElementsByClassName("condicional")[i].style.display="block";}
else{ 
for (var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('condicional').length;i+=1){
  document.getElementsByClassName("condicional")[i].style.display="none";} }
}
```

But I get the following error when I try to load the function in the chrome console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)

Any idea how can I make it work ?

Thanks !

PS: I am using Contact Form 7 on WordPress

**UPDATE:**

oops I was missing a }, that's all. However it doesnt work :(

The link: http://draidel.com.ar/trabaja-con-nosotros/

Comment: Use jQuery, it's much less hastle. First you need to hide your `.condicional`. Then just check on selected with `jQuery('#puesto option:selected')` if it is the selected value, then show the conditionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statement replace

```
    valor == "Modelo" or valor == "Promotor/a"
```

for

```
    valor == "Modelo" || valor == "Promotor/a"
```

The or operand in javascript is `||`

look at this documentation for more details. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

> Español

En la sentencia if remplaza

```
    valor == "Modelo" or valor == "Promotor/a"</pre>
```

por

```
    valor == "Modelo" || valor == "Promotor/a"
```

El operador lógico `or` en javascript es `||`

La documentación en español para mas detalles:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos

Comment: Hello!, I did what you told me but still the **same** error :(